# Arduino FM transmitter

Tags: sensors

I am wondering if it's possible to transmit on all frequencies at once using [this module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MS9RO2Y).

I know it's illegal to take over regular stations when others are trying to listen but I'm only planning to use it for short range (less than the length of my house).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a receiver only, not a transmitter.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if it's possible to transmit on all frequencies at once using this module.

it is definitely possible to transmit on all frequencies at once ***NOT*** using that module: square waves are a combination of all sorts of frequencies and your arduino is good at producing that.